# Происхождение названия "солярка"

Tags: этимология

Мне всегда было интересно, почему дизельное топливо называется "солярка"? Ясно, что слово происходит от "солнце", но при чем тут оно к дизельному двигателю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просторечие от солярового масла. Первое время, наряду с дизтопливом, использовалось для заправки техники. Сейчас соляровое масло для заправки почти не используют, но слово "солярка" прижилось.

Само соляровое масло получило название от английского "solar oil", там же, по всей видимости, из-за жёлтого цвета данного продукта.

Comment: Используют - и еще как.  
Только не в транспортной технике (там, согласен, только дизтопливо), а на движках для насосов, электродвижках - и проч.  
Кстати, дизтопливо - это обычно и есть солярка, разбавленная бензином. В разных пропорциях, обычно - 70 к 30.